# Component that was taken from a UI library has a small lag when displaying it with other UI component

Tags: reactjs

I have implemented a form with two input fields, as this image shows. This popup was implemented with ReactDOM.createPortal, and it works as expected, but when the popup is displayed in the initial loading time, there is a small delay to show the input fields and other elements will be displayed to user, and then one sec later input fields will be displayed. How can I overcome this? I tried to use React suspense with lazy loading. But since this is getting from a library, Can we use lazy loading or any other solution?

```
          <Stack sx={{px: '1.5rem', height: '17.975rem'}}>
            <Text sx={{...textRegular}}>
                {t('Enter a trading partner id below to add a new supplier to your list.')}
            </Text>
            <Stack sx={{borderBottom: '1px solid #ddd', pb: '1.5rem'}}>
                <Input type={'number'} required={true} label={t('Some input 1')}/>

                <Input type={'text'} required={true} label={t('Some input 2')}/>
            </Stack>
            <Stack direction={'row'} sx={{justifyContent: 'flex-end', mt: '1rem !important', pb: '1.5rem'}}>
                <Button type={'secondary'} label={t('Cancel')} onClick={close}/>
                <Button type={'primary'} label={t('Add ')}
                           disabled={disableButtons} onClick={handleSubmit}/>
            </Stack>
        </Stack>
```

[image]